# Open with Google Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is it possible to make a Chrome app handle certain types of extensions?
For example, setting a Chrome app to be launched when you double click a .txt file, instead of launching the Chrome app first and browsing for the file.

Comment: @Losiowaty I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on ChromeOS via [file_handlers](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/file_handlers.html). On other operating systems, not yet.

The bug to track this work on Windows: https://crbug.com/130455
Linux: https://crbug.com/138665

I'm not sure if / where there is a mac bug but it is also planned.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you : http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000128.htm
Especially the part at the end of it.
In the future - Google it, it was like the 2 result.

Comment: When I navigate to the shortcut of the Chrome app that way, it opens the file with Google Chrome web browser, not the Google Chrome app.